# MUI 5 - border radius on table body and table footer not working

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, html-table, material-ui

I am working on a new project (React 18.2 and MUI 5.10.3)
I have to create a table with particular styles in one of my components.

1. table head should not have a border
2. table body must have a border-radius
3. if the table footer exists, it must have a border-bottom radius

my problem is the border radius is not working on MUI tables. how can I add border-radius and remove the table head border? just like the pic I attached

by the way, I have searched many times I didn't find any good solution

this is what I made (without any extra styles):
https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-agnesi-t3ux1x?file=/src/App.tsx

and this is what I want to create:
[image]

Comment: .MuiTableCell-head {
        border: 0;
    } to remove the borders from table-head, i cant seem to figure out how to add border radius to your table tho

Answer (score -1):

I think overwrite datagrid with

```
sx={
".MuiDataGrid-root": {
        borderRadius:"50px",
    },
".MuiDataGrid-columnHeaders": {
        display:'none',
    }
}
```